# работа с файлами определенного формата в директории

Tags: python

Всем привет! У меня есть часть кода, которая ссылается на файл в той же директории, где лежит скрипт.

```
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
```

Вопрос:
Как мне правильно указать путь, чтобы скрипт работал со всеми файлами в нужной мне директории формате .xlsx
По моему это должно быть что-то типа

```
wb = load_workbook('mydir/*.xlsx')
```

но я понимаю что не прав.
Пожалуйста, помогите

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob
import os.path

for name in glob.glob('mydir/*.xlsx'):
    if os.path.isfile(name):
        wb = load_workbook(name)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Вот только почему то функции, описанные ниже работают только с первым файлом в директории. Правильно понимаю, что теперь все ниже описанные функции нужно описать в единую функцию и заставлять работать, пока файлы в папке не закончатся ?

Comment: зависит от того что вы хотите. обычно все операции выполняются рекурсивно или последовательно внутри цикла

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую полюбить модуль "***pathlib***"

```
from pathlib import Path
xls_files = [obj for obj in Path("mydir/").iterdir() if obj.is_file() and obj.suffix in {".xls", ".xlsx"} ]
```

а дальше - зависит от того как организована ваша  *load_workbook*. Судя по названию - надо так

```
for obj in xls_files:
    wb = load_workbook(obj.name)
```

Важная деталь - проверка на то что найденный объект является файлом.
Предыдущий ответ с модулем "***glob***"  выдаст и папки, если кто захочет их создать с именем типа "name.xlsx".
Как минимум в винде это возможно.
Конечно можно короче:

```
for obj in Path("mydir/").iterdir():
    if obj.suffix in {".xls", ".xlsx"} and obj.is_file():
         wb = load_workbook(obj.name)
```